# Linking Text on Fragments

Tags: android, xml, android-fragments, kotlin

Its easy to link texts on MainActivity.kt file but I can't figure  out how to link the same on a Fragment.kt file cause the functions are different. 
This is the code for MainActivity.kt

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    var text: TextView? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        text = findViewById(R.id.textLink)
        text?.setOnClickListener({
            var click = Intent (this@MainActivity, LinkText:: class.java)
            startActivity(click)
        })

    }
}
```

I want to link the text in HomeFragment.kt which looks like this

```
class HomeFragment : Fragment() {


    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, null)


    }


}
```

I need the code for the same.

Comment: What do you want to do? Do you have 2 `TextView`s one in the `Activity` and one in the `Fragment`, or do you want to update the text in `Activity` from the `Fragment`

Comment: I want to make my text linkable in HomeFragment.kt. My Text = "Fiction"  Text Id="fiction". This text will be linked to another Fragment called Fiction,kt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose that in `fragment_home.xml` you have a TextView with id `textLink`. Here is code how to "link" text on the `HomeFragment`.

```
class HomeFragment : Fragment() {

    var text: TextView? = null

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false)
        text = view.findViewById(R.id.textLink)
        text?.setOnClickListener {
            var click = Intent(requireActivity(), LinkText::class.java)
            startActivity(click)
        }
        return view
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanx but, var click = Intent(HomeFragment(), Fiction :: class.java) has an error in Intent telling "None of the fuctions can be called as the argument supplied"

Comment: Just use `var click = Intent(requireActivity(), Fiction :: class.java)`.